# Mongo record not updating, no error either

Tags: mongodb

Here is the record that I want to update:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("519177384e2e9fee10000000"),
    "fb_id" : { "0" : "2000" },
    "name" : { "0" : "Aaa Bbb" },
    "email" : { "0" : "abc@abc.com" }
}
```

I would like to fb_id to be changed to `"2000"`, instead of `{ "0" : "2000" }`.

I tried..

```
PRIMARY> db.users.update({fb_id : "{ 0 : 2000 }"},{$set: {fb_id: "2000"}});
```

It did not work but it did not through any error either. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to move the double quotes:

```
db.users.update({fb_id : { "0" : "2000" }},{$set: {fb_id: "2000"}})
```